# Clojure core.async in core.test

Tags: unit-testing, asynchronous, clojure, core.async

I have some core.async code with a pipeline of two chans and three nodes :

- a producer - function that puts values into chan1 with >!! (it's not in a go-block but the function is called from inside a go-loop)
- a filter - another function that's not in a go-block but is called within a go-loop,  which pulls items from chan1 (with <!!), does a test and if the test passes pushes them onto chan2 (with >!!)
- a consumer - an ordinary loop that pulls n values of chan2 with

This code works as expected when I run it as a simple program. But when I copy and paste it to work within a unit-test, it freezes up.

My test code is roughly

```
(deftest a-test 
  (testing "blah"  
    (is (= (let [c1 (chan)
                 c2 (chan)                 
                 gen (make-generator c1)
                 filt (make-filter c1 c2)
                 result (collector c2 10) ]
              result)
           [0 2 4 6 8 10 12 14 16 18 20]))
))
```

where the `generator` creates a sequence of integers counting up from zero and the `filter` tests for evenness.

As far as I can tell, the filter is able to pull the first value from the c1, but is blocked waiting for a second value. Meanwhile, the generator is blocking while waiting to push its next value into c1.

But this doesn't happen when I run the code in a simple stand-alone program.

So, is there any reason that the unit-test framework might be interfering or causing problems with the threading management that core.async is providing? Is it possible to do unit-testing on async code like this?

I'm concerned that I'm not running the collector in any kind of go-block or go-loop so presumably it might be blocking the main thread. But equally, I presume I have to pull all the data back into the main thread eventually. And if not through that mechanism, how?

Comment: Why would you use blocking puts and takes within go-blocks? This is usually a [bad idea](http://martintrojer.github.io/clojure/2014/03/09/working-with-coreasync-blocking-calls).

Comment: I'm not inside a go-block ... I'm inside a function that's called from a go-loop .. but Clojure doesn't seem to let me use <! and >! there.

Comment: Maybe I'm not understanding async. What I want is a separate thread for the generator and filter objects. But I don't mind them blocking their own thread when waiting for the next input or for the output channel to be available. But i'm mystified how I'm finding myself deadlocked here.

Comment: did you try using `(async/thread (loop [...` instead of `(async/go-loop [...`?

Comment: no ...  let me have a look ...

Comment: OK. Yes, that's the answer I needed. (thread) If you make it an answer here I'll accept it. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While using blocking IO within `go`-blocks/`go`-loops isn't the best solution, `thread` macro may be better fit here. It will execute passed body on separate thread, so you may freely use blocking operations there.